# Structural Type Parameters in Scala Collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections, structural-typing

***Disclaimer:*** *This is a question of what is **possible**, not what would be recommended in practice.*

Let's say you're given the following classes:

```
case class point1(x: Int, y:Int)
case class point2(x: Int, y:Int)
case class point3(x: Int, y:Int)
```

and you have lists containing some number of each class

```
val points1 = List[point1](/*Can be empty for this example*/)
val points2 = List[point2]()
val points3 = List[point3]()
```

is it possible to create a list of a structural type that can contain all three point types using the usual techniques like `++`, `:::`, or `.union(..)` without defining a common trait that all the classes extend, i.e.

```
var points: List[{def x: Int; def y: Int}] = 
    points1 ::: points2 ::: points3
```

I understand that as written above, the `:::` operator returns a `List[Product]`.  I assume it's a matter of providing the right hints to the Scala compiler, because the following code does produce a list of the correct type:

```
var points: ListBuffer[{def x: Int; def y: Int}] = List[{def x: Int; def y: Int}]()
points1.foreach( e => {
    val p: {def x: Int; def y: Int} = e;
    points.append(p);
})
points2.foreach( e => {
    val p: {def x: Int; def y: Int} = e;
    points.append(p);
})
```

Are there any hints I can give to help the Scala compiler to select the correct type for `:::` and produce a List of the structural type specified?

Comment: You have your answer, but be aware that the cost of invoking a method (or accessing a property, which is the same thing) is significantly higher when a structural type is being used.

Comment: @RandallSchulz Thanks, as I stated in the **disclaimer**, this is not code being used in practice, just a thought experiment on what is possible with Scala's structural type system and inferencing.  I understand that combining structural typing, especially with implicit conversions, can have serious performance impacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(points1 : List[{val x : Int; val y : Int}]) ::: points2 ::: points3
```

Should work!

Comment: Thank you.  A few minutes after posting I found my real problem which wasn't really related to the question I asked above.  In the real example, the `point3` class does not exactly match the the other two, and relies on implicit conversions. I was missing a hint to trigger the implicit conversion, which was causing `:::` to revert to using `List[Product]` as the return type.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the following code:

```
var points: List[{def x: Int; def y: Int}] = 
points1 ::: points2 ::: points3
```

It works:

```
implicit def typer[B >: A, A <: { def x: Int; def y: Int }](t: List[B]): List[A] = t

var points: List[{def x: Int; def y: Int}] = 
points1 ::: points2 ::: points3
```